# react-bootstrap Tabs have underline

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap framework, and I ran into an issue with the Tabs/Tab components not displaying correctly. There's an underline under the active tab:

[imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVPbD.jpg)

Here's the render code:

```
const React = require('react');
const { Tabs, Tab } = require('react-bootstrap');

const Account = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            activeTab: 1,
        };
    },
    componentWillMount() {
        const section = this.props.params.section ? this.props.params.section : 'contact';
        let activeTab;

        switch (section) {
            case 'contact':
                activeTab = 1;
                break;
            case 'security':
                activeTab = 2;
                break;
            case 'notifications':
                activeTab = 3;
                break;
            default:
                // default to contact tab
                activeTab = 1;
                break;
        }

        this.setState({ activeTab });
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="u__narrow">
                <h1 className="__page-title">Your Account</h1>
                <Tabs id="accountSections" activeKey={this.state.activeTab} onSelect={key => this.setState({activeTab: key })}>
                    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Contact Info">
                        <ContactInfo />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Password & Security">
                        <Security />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Email Notifications">
                        <Notifications />
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        );
    },
});

module.exports = Account;
```

I'm doing the exact thing as the documentation, but I'm encountering the underline issue

Comment: Judging from the image you have posted and the image from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs-controlled it looks like you are missing the css for these components. How are you getting the bootstrap css into your app? react-bootstrap doesn't provide it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you don't have the bootstrap css linked in your page. See teh stylesheets section on the documention, React Bootstrap doesn't include any css oyu need to bring it yourself. http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html